# My dynamic onclick for my anchor attribute not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have my jQuery adding **onclick** event to a dynamic **anchor** tag, and when the user clicks on the anchor tag, it will pass the **id** of the anchor tag that was clicked. Is there something wrong with my script?

Sorry I'm just new to javascript started 3days ago.

```
jQuery('#WMVideoxx').on('click','a',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   MyFunction(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
}); 

function MyFunction(anchor)
{
}
```

Comment: are you sure your javascript code is executing after the dynamic element has been created?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's executing or not, but when I checked my console, there's no error, and all jQuery and ajax executed before ths part. So if ever it doesn't execute? what caused the jQuery to not execute?

Answer (score 1):

**How about this?**

```js
$('#WMVideoxx').html('<a id="youFoundMe">Dynamic Anchor</a>').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="WMVideoxx" style="height:100px; width:300px;">
</div>
```

Comment: where is the part that i'm passing the ID of the anchor tag to my function?

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine, like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#WMVideoxx').on('click','a',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    MyFunction(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
  }); 
});


function MyFunction(anchorId) {
  alert(anchorId);
}
</script>
<div id="WMVideoxx" style="height:100px; width:300px;">
  <a href="#" id="anchor1">1</a><br/>
  <a href="#" id="anchor5">5</a><br/>
  <a href="#" id="anchor17">17</a><br/>
  <a href="#" id="anchor32">32</a><br/>
  <a href="#" id="anchor55">5</a><br/>
</div>
```

---

Okay, here is an answer with an added button that adds anchors

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery('#WMVideoxx').on('click','a',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    MyFunction(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
  }); 
});

function MyFunction(anchorId) {
  alert(anchorId);
}
var counter = 0;
function plus_one() {
  counter++;
  jQuery('#WMVideoxx').append('<a href="'+ counter +'" id="anchor'+ counter +'">'+ counter +'</a><br/>');
}
</script>
<div id="WMVideoxx" style="height:100px; width:300px;"></div>
<hr><button onclick="plus_one()" value="+1"> Add anchor
```

---

( I'm not sure if the other answers understand the question.  This extra ,'a' must not be removed. 
jQuery used to do this with .bind() or .live(); today we use .on()  .

The idea is: this will also work for anchors that are dynamically added, long after the page load.

So the listener will keep an eye on the div (id="WMVideoxx"), and will be listening to a click on any childnode; at the moment of the click the on() will check for all the childnodes.
)

Comment: Okay, just a minute, I'll add a +1 anchor button

Comment: yes you're right, that's the point of sequence of my code also, but i don't know why the click event is like not hitting,

Answer (score 0):

Example full html doc showing 1) remove second attribute from your .on function (the 'a') and ensure you try to apply the event handler once the element exists:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src=jquery-1.12.2.min.js></script>
<style>
#WMVideoxx { width:100px; height:100px; background:#f00; cursor:pointer; }
</style>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Test</h1>
<div id=WMVideoxx></div>
</body>
</html>
<script>
$('#WMVideoxx').on('click',function(e){
                                        e.preventDefault();
                                        MyFunction(jQuery(this).attr('id'));
                                    }); 

function MyFunction(anchor)
{
alert ("Anchor was "+anchor);
}
</script>
```